# Running through 15 hdf5 in a directory to compute a function, but getting reiterations of the same table over again

Tags: python, function, loops, iteration, hdf5

I've currently written a code to run through all the hdf5 files in a directory, print out the tables from the files, plot a figure for each table, and then spit out the area under the curve for each. This is the code.

```
import os
directory = '/Users/xx'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".hdf5"):
        xdata = file.get('data')
        xdata= np.array(xdata)
        xdata_df = pd.DataFrame(xdata)
        table1 = pd.DataFrame(xdata_df).reset_index() 
        print(table1)
        x = table1["index"]
        y = table1[0]        
        plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
        plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 20})
        figure1 = plt.plot(x, y)
        

        # Compute the area using the composite trapezoidal rule.
        area = trapz(y, dx=100000)
        print("trapz area =", area)

        # Compute the area using the composite Simpson's rule.
        area = simps(y, dx=100000)
        print("simpsons area =", area)
        continue
    else:
            continue
```

However, my code seems to running through the directory (15 files), but spitting out the exact same table 15 times, figure and area under the curve. Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, to get the Y values, you should use `y = table1[1]`,and not `y = table1[0]`. You read the  values as `x = table1["index"]` - you should use `x = table1[0]`. Also, do you realize you aren't using `x` when you call`trpz()` and `simps()`. You are creating 2 dataframes: `xdata_df` and `table1` and only use `table1` - Why? If you just need the X/Y data, you can read the values directly from the dataset (dataframes are not required).

Note: code above is missing `h5py.File()` to open the H5 file.

Finally, you can simplify and cleanup your code as follows:

```
for filename in glob.iglob(f'{directory}/*.hdf5'):
    with h5py.File(filename,'r') as file:
        xdata = file['data'][()]
        x = xdata[:,0] # or x = file['data'][:,0]
        y = xdata[:,1] # or y = file['data'][:,1]       

        # Compute the area using the composite trapezoidal rule.
        area = trapz(y, dx=100000)
        print("trapz area =", area)

        # Compute the area using the composite Simpson's rule.
        area = simps(y, dx=100000)
        print("simpsons area =", area)
```

Or, if you prefer to use dataframes:

```
for filename in glob.iglob(f'{directory}/*.hdf5'):
    with h5py.File(filename,'r') as file:
        xdata = file['data'][()]
        xdata_df = pd.DataFrame(xdata)
        table1 = pd.DataFrame(xdata_df).reset_index() 
        x = table1[0]
        y = table1[1]  

        # Compute the area using the composite trapezoidal rule.
        area = trapz(y, dx=100000)
        print("trapz area =", area)

        # Compute the area using the composite Simpson's rule.
        area = simps(y, dx=100000)
        print("simpsons area =", area)
```